# Powermock withArguments call with variable input

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito, junit4, powermockito

I have test and class under test, which uses time in file name.

Test code:

```
SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormatTimestamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyMMddHHmmss");

String outputpath= inboundDir+inboundFilePrefix+simpleDateFormatTimestamp.format(new Date())+".txt";
PowerMockito.whenNew(File.class).withArguments(outputpath).thenReturn(outputFileToInboundDir);
```

Class under test Code:

```
File outputFile=new File(inboundDir+inboundFilePrefix+simpleDateFormatTimestamp.format(new Date())+".txt");
```

Also in test and class under test, i have other new file calls so i am not able to use withAnyArguments mocking. when i use withAnyArguments only one mock gets returned for all the new file calls.

My test case pass sometime and fails other times depending on test and class under test runs in same second ("yyMMddHHmmss") or not.

How do i remove this test failure, when class and test execute in different second.

Thanks

Comment: You have said "Also in test and class under test, i have other new file calls" . Does all the calls take date as the argument?

Comment: other new file calls do not have date in file path argument. file path is constant in other calls.

Answer (score 0):

This is one possible solution.

```
String outputpath= inboundDir+inboundFilePrefix+simpleDateFormatTimestamp.format(new Date())+".txt";
PowerMockito.whenNew(File.class).withAnyArguments().thenAnswer(invocation -> {
    String firstArgument = (String) invocation.getArguments()[0];
    // do a pattern matching for firstArgument with a regex containing date in it. 
    // if its true then return outputpath
    // else return something else
});
```

We could have used ArgumentCaptor but, `PowerMockito.whenNew` doesn't support that.

Answer (score 0):

The Workaround which worked for me is as below.

Since i had only one such call in test, i removed variable part simpleDateFormatTimestamp.format(new Date())+".txt"

Now if i do below it worked fine.

`String outputpath= inboundDir+inboundFilePrefix;`
`PowerMockito.whenNew(File.class).withArguments(startsWith(outputpath)).thenReturn(outputFileToInboundDir);`

startsWith Matcher is available in org.mockito.Mockito